# Print Win or Lose in NetLogo using If-Else Statement

Tags: if-statement, simulation, netlogo

So this is the progress of the simulation that I am making. This simulation has a list of players and each players has their assigned points or score. I have a patch called games. There are thirty games. Once the player hit the game (or if they will meet on the simulation) then there will be a label showing, "hit" which is already done. Each of the thirty games also has their own points. The points is generated randomly.

So my question is that how will I be able to show on assign the players if they have won or not won the game? My condition is that if the player has a point greater than or equal to the points of the game then it should show "You won the game!" else "You lose!" this happens when the player and game meets.

I will place another variable on my players-own that would indicate if it won or lose. But my problem is, I kept on trying to code the if-else/if on the move procedure for the condition that I want but I'm having a hard time. I need help or some clue on how to do this. Thanks.

```
breed [players player]
breed [games game]
globals [namelist pointslist]
players-own[name points] ;;going to add another variable here
games-own[points istaken]

to setup 
  ca
  ask patches [set pcolor black]
  set namelist["Player 1" "Player 2" "Player 3" "Player 4" "Player 5" "Player 6" "Player 7" "Player 8" "Player 9" "Player 10"]
  set pointslist["1" "1" "1" "5" "3" "3" "4" "2" "2" "5"]

  ;;define counter
  let counter 0 ;;0-9

  repeat 10 [
    create-players 1[
  set name item counter namelist
  set points item counter pointslist
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  set shape "person"
  pen-down
]
  set counter counter + 1
  ]

  create-games 30[
    set shape "circle"
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set points random 5 + 1 ;
  ]

  reset-ticks
end 

to go
  tick
  ask players[move]
end

;;this is the part where I added my if-else code but i cannot get it
to move
  ask players [
right(random 181) - 90
fd 1
let hw one-of games-here 
if hw != nobody[

  ask hw [set label "hit"]
    ]
  ]

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is not completely clear, but I think this responds to your question.  (See the very end for your needed `ifelse` statement.)

```
globals [namelist pointslist]
breed [players player]
players-own[name points] ;;going to add another variable here
breed [games game]
games-own[points istaken]

to setup 
  ca
  ask patches [set pcolor black]
  set namelist["Player 1" "Player 2" "Player 3" "Player 4" "Player 5" "Player 6" "Player 7" "Player 8" "Player 9" "Player 10"]
  set pointslist[1 1 1 5 3 3 4 2 2 5]  ;use numbers, not strings!

  ;;define counter
  let _counter 0 ;;0-9

  create-players 10 [
    set name item _counter namelist
    set points item _counter pointslist
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "person"
    pen-down
    set _counter (_counter + 1)
  ]

  create-games 30 [
    set shape "circle"
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set points random 5 + 1 ;
  ]
  reset-ticks
end 

to go
  ask players[move]
  tick
end

;;this is the part where I added my if-else code but i cannot get it
to move
  ;ask players [  ;ai don't ask player to ask players!
  right(random 181) - 90
  fd 1
  let _hw one-of games-here 
  if _hw != nobody [
    ask _hw [set label "hit"]
    ifelse (points > [points] of _hw) [ ;comparison of two *numbers*
      show "won the game"
    ] [
      show "lost the game"
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. I would like to ask, why players should not ask players? The one in your comment...

Comment: I would also like to ask this line of code "ifelse (points > [points] of _hw"

Comment: In `go` you have `ask players [move]`.  This is good.  but then you have `move` start with `ask players`.  This means that each player is going to ask all players to do the `move` actions.  With 10 players, the move actions are executed 100 times per tick instead of 10 times.           You gave a `points` attribute to both players and games, but players are running the move action.  When a player is running the move action, `points` refers to its points.  (You could replace it with `[points] of self`.) hth